# How to drop the warning "conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value"

Tags: c, casting

I though that if I `cast` a number like this `(unsigned char)32` it will be enough to fix the compiler warning, but it wasn't like how I planed.

Here i have the following part of the program which actually explain the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *ptr = malloc(6);
    const char *name = "MICHI";
    unsigned int i = 0;

    if(ptr){
        strcpy(ptr, name);
        ptr[strlen(ptr)] = '\0';
    }else{
        return 1;
    }

    while(ptr[i] != '\0'){
        if((ptr[i] >= 'A') && (ptr[i] <= 'Z')){
            ptr[i] += (unsigned char)32;
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("Name = %s\n",ptr);
    if(ptr){
        free(ptr);
        ptr = NULL;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it with compiler warnings ON, I get this:

```
error: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]|
```

This means thet the following `ptr[i] += (unsigned char)32;` doesn't provide a solution to my problem.

My question is, how to drop this warning because I have no clue about it.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/QWrcDl) doesn't helps to much, because I think that all warnings  are Turned off.

Comment: Why do you need the cast?

Comment: because I can't compile the code.

Comment: use `tolower()`..done. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh `| 0x20` .. done :)

Comment: @2501 I think it doesn't display any warnings..

Comment: Ideone doesn't have warnings turned ON at all. Is not useful for me.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes it doesn't, but if you enable additional warnings with gcc ,which ideone doesn't enable, you get warnings.

Comment: @2501 Yes, and I need a fix to can compile that code with flags turned On

Comment: @Michi: Agreed it is annoying. But logical. `#pragma` `push`/`ignore`/`pop` the warning if you really need the special semantics of the compound assignment. Otherwise use the long form.

Comment: @Olaf Thank you. I will have to read about `#pragma`. I learn `C` just for fun.

Comment: Aside:  If intent on not using `tolower()`, rather than magic number `32`, use `('a' - 'A')`.  It conveys code's intent better (And works in [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) as well as ASCII)

Comment: @chux `use ('a' - 'A')` Could you please provide an Example? I tried this `ptr[i] += ('a' - 'A');` but with same results `conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value` .

Comment: hint ('a' - 'A') is equal to 32.

Comment: @Michi, My comment is an "aside".  It does not fix your warning issue, but addresses a weakness in the coding style.

Comment: You could also consider a table solution. You could create an array with the lowercase alphabet and use the uppercase letter to index into this array. Like so. char *lowercase="abcde... etc"; ptr[I] = lowercase[ptr[I]-'A']; If you (or the compiler) don't like the ptr[I]-'A' part then you could create a table with the entire character set with the uppercase letters replaced with lowercase letters and then you could just use lowercase[ptr[I]] Of course this is just writing your own version of tolower.

Comment: @Stuart nice example. I will give it a try too. Thank you.

Comment: @Stuart A typical mistake in making a table is not accounting the `char` could be signed and thus make negative indexes.  Do-able, but be careful.

Comment: @Stuart If you meant something like [this](http://ideone.com/8Xkw4h) , works fine with no warnings.

Comment: @chux true, your answer to the question is the solution I would use.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to null terminate a string after you strcpy into it (strcpy copies the null terminator also). I'm not sure you realize this but "MICHI" has a null terminator at the end.

Comment: @Stuart Oh, you right :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP is using a level of warning that is very picky

> warning: conversion to 'char' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]

```
  // Both cause the warning
  ptr[i] += (unsigned char) 32;
  ptr[i] = tolower(ptr[i]);
```

To address the warning, be explicit

```
  ptr[i] = (char) (ptr[i] + 32);
  ptr[i] = (char) tolower(ptr[i]);
```

---

[Detail] Operations that involving narrow type like `char, short, unsigned char, _Bool, ...` will have that operand promoted, using the usual *integer promotions* to `int/unsigned`, like `ptr[i]`.  So assigning that `int/unsigned` back to a `char` triggers the warning.  An explicit cast of the result quiets the warning.

Many compilations omit the `[-Wconversion] or equivalent` option and so will not see the warning.

Comment: Note: Should one go the `tolower()` route, a pedantic solution would use `ptr[i] = (char) tolower((unsigned char) ptr[i]);` ,  but that is a `is...()` issue.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
ptr[i] += (unsigned char)32;
```

really means:

```
ptr[i] = ptr[i] + 32;
```

Now... `ptr[i]` may legally be as big as 255.  And if you added 255 + 32, you'd get 287.

***How do you propose to fit value 287 inside a `char`, which has a maximum value of 255?***
 You just cannot do that.  That is what the error is about.

If you want to get rid of the error, you must first be clear in your own mind about what exactly you want to happen when addition might create values larger than a `char` can hold.

If you are simply trying to convert the letters **A-Z** into their lowercase equivalents, just use the ***appropriate*** api for that: [`tolower`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/)

---

If you're really not going to use `tolower`, then try this:

```
ptr[i] = (unsigned char)(ptr[i] + 32);
```

The important difference is that the type-cast is on the ***result*** of the calculation, and not on one of the ***operands*** of the operation.

Comment: `Now... ptr[i] may legally be as big as 255` I tough that `if((ptr[i] >= 'A') && (ptr[i] <= 'Z'))` prevent that, or you mean that my code is not safe ?

Comment: Your if-statement will limit ptr[i].  But the compiler does not know that!  It cannot consider all the consequences of every if-statement.  As far as the compiler knows, ptr[i] has type `char`, and any `char` may be 0-255.

Comment: That was may point. The program it should be safe. But i can't compile it with compiler warnings turned ON

Comment: Why is `ptr` a `char*` but you're adding an `unsigned char` to it?

Comment: `ptr[i] = (unsigned char)(ptr[i] + 32);` is the same. It doesn't work

Comment: @Michi Compiler can't infer it is safe, it does not perform any kind of static/dynamic analysis. It is only performing typechecks. If you are certain your code is OK even though it doesn't type-check - you can ignore the warning. Or use any of the solutions you have been provided.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How can I ignore the compiler Warning without disable the warnings, in which case isn't what i need?

Comment: How about ***not*** ignoring warnings, and actually ***understanding*** what they mean, and finding an ***appropriate*** way to address them, not  hack your way around them.

Comment: @Michi there is a plenty of ways to write the code doing the same *without* warnings. But it looks like you are insisting on using *this* way. So the only option is to have this warning and ignore it. Ore dsable it locally using `pragma`s..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Agreed. Yet it really is annoying. Especially in embedded programming when doing bitops, a more intelligent checking would be useful. Even more, as there actually **is** a difference when evaluating the lvalue (see n1570, 6.5.16.2p3).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Should I understand that a direct `cast` doesn't fix this?

Comment: @Michi You can see it is not. I don't see a proper way to fix it with casts only.

Comment: @Michi Actually there is. See my answer.

Comment: Using `tolower()` generates the same waning - as it should.

Comment: Yes, with `tolower()` I get the same warning.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the comments, there *is* actually a way of silencing the warning using casts only:

```
ptr[i] = (char)((int)ptr[i]  + 32);
```

This way the deal with the conversion is delegated to the assignment operator, which is (as pointed by @Olaf) defined in the [Standard, 6.5.16.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p3).

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because there is a possibility that you may overrun the boundary of a `char` value.

Usually, *avoiding* the warning is not a good idea, in general.

Use [`tolower()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower) to get the job done in a cleaner way.