# Conversion to "USHORT" from 'int' may alter its value

Tags: c, type-conversion, unsigned

I'm having some troubles in adapting a piece of code for an embedded platform.

```
eMBFuncReadCoils( UCHAR * pucFrame, USHORT * usLen )
```

The line above is the prototype of the function I'm having troubles with.

The problem is about the `*usLen` pointer with the following instruction:

```
*usLen += 1;
```

USHORT is defined as follows:

```
typedef unsigned short USHORT;
```

Compiler says:

```
error: conversion to 'USHORT' from 'int' may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]
         *usLen += 1;
```

I cannot figure out what might be the problem.

And why it's bringing up an error because of `int` ?

I also thought to rewrite the assignment like this:

```
*usLen = *usLen + 1;
```

But nonetheless noting changes.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the same problem with `*usLen++`?

Comment: It seems to work but it gives me another error: error: value computed is not used, and I agree with that because incrementing it with ++, just increments it local value in that statement, the incremented value is never reassigned to the memory location pointed by that pointer

Comment: Or try "*usLen += (USHORT)1". Your original statement takes int 1, converts usLen to int, adds them, then tries to assign them back to short. If value is 0xffff, you probably have an issue.

Comment: same error :(, btw I found a non very beautiful solution, I do my operation on a non pointer helper variable then assign the value to the dereferenced pointer.

Comment: What compiler is this and what architecture, btw?

Comment: arm-none-eabi-gcc that compiles for the STM32F4 (Cortex M4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the compiler option (`[-Werror=conversion]`) is to blame here. The expression `*usLen += 1;` is syntactic sugar for that one:

```
*usLen = *usLen + 1;
```

So you add an unsigned short and an int. The unsigned short value is promoted to an int (assumint int can represent all unsigned short values which is true for all common 32 and 64 bits architectures), and you end up assigning an int to an unsigned short which *can* truncate values but is perfectly defined by C standard. It is normally a warning on common options, but here the error says that the compiler was specifically instructed to raise an error.

You can either relax the compiler options, or if you have good reasons for them, just use an explicit conversion which should be allowed:

```
*usLen += (unsigned short) 1;
```

or

```
*usLen = (unsigned short) (*usLen + 1);
```

Comment: The As far of my concern **1** is an integer constant(literal) so the compiler apply the right rules here, because when you do **a+=b** is not the always the same as **a = a + b**. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439640/how-to-drop-the-warning-conversion-to-char-from-int-may-alter-its-value) .

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 1 is considered as an int, and (*uslen + 1) the result of the operation is an int too, then the affectation in a ushort may lead to loss of information.
For info :
ushort are coded on 2 bytes form 0 to 65535
int are coded on 2 or 4 (depending on the compiler and processor) from -32 768 to 32 767 or form -2 147 483 648 to 2 147 483 647
Perhaps you souhld try something like
*usLen = *usLen + (USHORT) 1;
or
*usLen = (USHORT)(*usLen + (USHORT) 1);
and test of the max value before doing the addition
Hope that could help

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `1` to `USHORT`:

1. `*usLen += (unsigned short) 1;`
2. `*usLen += (USHORT) 1;`